# Finding a finite sum of an alternating geometric series

Tags: calculus, discrete-mathematics

I'm trying to find the summation of a finite alternating geometric series.
I know that normally the sum of a geometric series can be calculated using 
$a\frac{1-r^n}{1-r}$. This same equation doesn't work for an alternating geometric series such as $(-2^n)$, where the series is $1,-2,4,-8,16$.
I'm looking to find the summation of the first 50 terms.

Comment: Why don't you think the same formula works?

Answer (score 6):

The same formula works. Evaluate $$\frac{a(1-r^n)}{1-r}$$ at $r=-2$.

For example when $n=3$, it is $$\frac{(1)(1-(-2)^3)}{1-(-2)}=3=1-2+4$$

Comment: Awesome thank you, so the issue is that my ratio isn't 2 but is -2.

Comment: yup, also note that $(-2)^n$ is different from $-2^n$.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the fact that the sum of two consecutive terms is $-2^{n-1}$, where you are adding the nth term and the n+1st term, so the sum of the first 50 terms is $\sum_{n=1}^{25}-2^{n-1}$, and go from there